# Unexpected result when sorting digits using Goroutines

Tags: go

I am doing some exercises in Go, and I have a strange behavior with my code. If someone could explain me the reason it could be really great.

Here is the code : https://play.golang.org/p/4fQYHWpD6Cj

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
)

func sortList (list []int, c chan []int) {
    sort.Ints(list)
    c <- list
}

func convert(sStr []string) (sInt []int){
cnvLoop: for _, r := range sStr {
    digit, err := strconv.Atoi(r)
    if err != nil {
        break cnvLoop
    }
    sInt = append(sInt, digit)
}
    return sInt
}

func split(list []int, size int) (tmpS []int, splS[]int) {
    tmpS = list[size:]
    splS = list[:size]
    return tmpS, splS
}

func main() {

    list := []string{"-9", "-11", "12", "13", "9"}
    fmt.Println("Your unsorted digits: ", list)
    sInt := convert(list)
    size := len(sInt) / 4


    tmpS, splS1 := split(sInt, size)
    tmpS, splS2 := split(tmpS, size)
    tmpS, splS3 := split(tmpS, size)
    splS4 := tmpS

    // sort in different go routines
    c := make(chan []int)
    go sortList(splS1, c)
    go sortList(splS2, c)
    go sortList(splS3, c)
    go sortList(splS4, c)

    // receive from a channel
    sortedS1 := <-c
    sortedS2 := <-c
    sortedS3 := <-c
    sortedS4 := <-c

    // merge the 4 sorted slices
    var sortedList1, sortedList2 []int
    sortedList1 = append(sortedS1, sortedS2...)
    sortedList2 = append(sortedS3, sortedS4...)
    finalList := append(sortedList1, sortedList2...)

    // we need to sort it again
    sort.Ints(finalList)
    fmt.Println("Here your digits sorted: ", finalList)
}
```

Now if you gonna test the code on Goplayground it will work every time, but if you run it on your computer the results may defer sometimes. (tried GoLand on Windows and vim-go on Ubuntu)

The purpose of this exercise is to just to input numbers on a slice, cut this slice on four part and sorts them using go routines and then merge them into one sorted slice.

The purpose of the exercise is totally silly, since I have to sort the big slice in the end anyway, so please put the purpose aside and so my algorithm since we could much simplify.

But the different results bugs me so much and I can't understand the problem since the last 24 hours.
This exercise just ruin all what I thought understand on channels and go routines.

Comment: Edit the question to show the unexpected results.

Comment: Please put the code directly into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your problem has nothing to do with channels, it's related to array/slice usage. You are using slices everywhere, so initially tere's only one copy of data - [`sort.Ints()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Ints) performs operation in place and channel also operates on slices. This means that until you `append`, there's only one array in memory.

And now [`append`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) does its job. Here's the key information from documentation:

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, append re-uses the underlying array.

According to that if capacity of slice is sufficient, `append` adds items to existing array (there's no reallocation) and overwrites previous data. So, the faulty part of your code is the consolidation part.

Comment: your explanation seems very correct, the thing is why it works if I move this lines of receiving data from the channels like this : https://play.golang.org/p/T5MrR3L2qFD

Another guy had this solution of the exercise and he is using slice, maybe less than me and his code works perfectly: https://play.golang.org/p/7rUwiu-yUJ6

Meanwhile I'm going to focus on the slices like you said and I'll tell you what on the comment section :)

Comment: The other solution you you showed works quite different. It allocates new array for each part of data. Key lines are 14 (`s := []int{}` - create new slice not bound to any array) and 17 (`s = append(s, j)` - extend and allocate array to fit data). So, it doesn't work on one copy of data.

Comment: Thank you very much Tupteq, you are totally right, I learned from this and it's cool. But still I feel like I could do the mistake again. I read that I should always append on the slice itself and not a copy of it. And since I named the function I returned, I have always a copy of my slice is that right? I need to clarify this pefectly in my mind.

Comment: Slices themselves don't contain any data, they only point to an array with data and  `append` works on that array. It uses slice's capacity to determine if there's a place to append to existing array (and to overwrite what was there before) or new array needs to be allocated to fit the data. So, it doesn't matter if you work on slice copy or original, important is the array pointed by it.

Answer (score 0):

All right I get the point but when I print the slice after the append loop the results of the append loop is correct every time and the final sorted result is incorrect.
Beside I took both code (the incorrect one and the correct one) I arranged them so they look similar and I still have different result, the only difference is on the incorrect one the whole slice is converted to int and spliced to 4, in the correct one they are spliced to 4 first and then converted
I can imagine the append in the second solution are made on small slices but still. I'm still confused, I'm still thinking there is some race condition problem.
Please take a look again on those two :

1- https://play.golang.org/p/-vOseYE1XLt

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
)

func send(slice []int, c chan []int) {
    sort.Ints(slice)
    c <- slice
}

// Split strings.
func split(list []string) (tmpS []string, splS []string) {
    tmpS = list[len(list)/2:]
    splS = list[0 : len(list)/2]
    return tmpS, splS
}

func convert(sStr []string) (sInt []int) {
    for _, r := range sStr {
        digit, _ := strconv.Atoi(r)
        sInt = append(sInt, digit)
    }
    fmt.Println("Sorted sub array: ", sInt)
    return sInt
}

func main() {
    list := []string{"-9", "-11", "12", "13", "9"}
    fmt.Println("Your unsorted digits: ", list)

    splS1, splS2 := split(list)
    splS11, splS12 := split(splS1)
    splS21, splS22 := split(splS2)

    // Convert each slices.
    sInt1 := convert(splS11)
    sInt2 := convert(splS12)
    sInt3 := convert(splS21)
    sInt4 := convert(splS22)

    // Send in different go routines.
    c := make(chan []int)
    go send(sInt1, c)
    go send(sInt2, c)
    go send(sInt3, c)
    go send(sInt4, c)

    // Receive from a channel.
    sortedS1 := <-c
    sortedS2 := <-c
    sortedS3 := <-c
    sortedS4 := <-c

    // Merge the 4 sorted slices.
    sortedList1 := append(sortedS1, sortedS2...)
    sortedList2 := append(sortedS3, sortedS4...)
    finalList := append(sortedList1, sortedList2...)

    // Sort it again
    sort.Ints(finalList)
    fmt.Println("Here your digits sorted: ", finalList)
}
```

2 -https://play.golang.org/p/L8WcrlTOVxZ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
)

func send(list []int, c chan []int) {
    sort.Ints(list)
    c <- list
}

// Split integers.
func split(list []int) (tmpS []int, splS []int) {
    tmpS = list[len(list)/2:]
    splS = list[0 : len(list)/2]
    return tmpS, splS
}

func convert(sStr []string) (sInt []int) {
    for _, r := range sStr {
        digit, _ := strconv.Atoi(r)
        sInt = append(sInt, digit)
    }
    fmt.Println("Sorted sub array: ", sInt)
    return sInt
}

func main() {
    list := []string{"-9", "-11", "12", "13", "9"}
    fmt.Println("Your unsorted digits: ", list)

    // Convert the whole slice
    sInt := convert(list)

    splS1, splS2 := split(sInt)
    splS11, splS12 := split(splS1)
    splS21, splS22 := split(splS2)

    // Send in different go routines.
    c := make(chan []int)
    go send(splS11, c)
    go send(splS12, c)
    go send(splS21, c)
    go send(splS22, c)

    // Receive from a channel.
    sortedS1 := <-c
    sortedS2 := <-c
    sortedS3 := <-c
    sortedS4 := <-c

    // Merge the 4 sorted slices.
    sortedList1 := append(sortedS1, sortedS2...)
    sortedList2 := append(sortedS3, sortedS4...)
    finalList := append(sortedList1, sortedList2...)

    // Sort it again
    sort.Ints(finalList)
    fmt.Println("Here your digits sorted: ", finalList)
}
```

Comment: All right, I get it now, you were totally right Tupteq thank you so much :)
The Problem was indeed on the last append because I used too many slices.